# ERROR : "Cannot Find FFMPEG" on Google Cloud Compute Engine Debian Wheezy 7.8 Managed Instance even though it's installed

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, debian, google-compute-engine

I wrote a Node.JS application that uses the `fluent-ffmpeg` module to watermark videos uploaded on the platform. I pushed the code to a my Google Cloud Compute Engine project, and every time I get `Error : Cannot Find FFMPEG`. I ssh'd into the instance once it was created and ran these commands to install `FFMPEG` before actually testing out the code. I am not sure what is causing the error because after this I am positive that `FFMPEG` is installed.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ffmpeg
export FFMPEG_PATH="/usr/bin/ffmpeg"
export FFPROBE_PATH="/usr/bin/ffprobe"
```

Below is my FFMPEG code

```
function generate_thumbnail(name, path){
  logging.info("Generating Thumbnail");
  ffmpeg(path)
   .setFfmpegPath('/usr/bin/ffmpeg') 
   .setFfprobePath('/usr/bin/ffprobe')
   .on('end', function() {
        upload_thumbnail(name);
        logging.info("Thumbnail Generated and uploaded");
        return;
    })
  .on('error', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        logging.info('ERROR: ' + err.message);
        logging.info('STDERR:' + stderr);
  })
  .on('start', function(commandLine) {
       logging.info(commandLine);
  })
  .screenshots({
    count: 1,
    filename: name + '_thumbnail.png',
    folder: 'public/images/thumbnails/'
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm having this problem now. How did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Can you execute `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` from the shell to verify if it's the correct path?

Also you can set path to the FFMPEG binary manually with [`setFfmpegPath`](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#setting-binary-paths-manually) method.

Comment: I executed it to make sure it's the right path and it is and I also tired the setFfmepg and setFfprobe methods but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I get this message now when I run the ffmpeg command after ssh'ing
" The ffmpeg program is only provided for script compatibility and will be removed
in a future release. It has been deprecated in the Libav project to allow for
incompatible command line syntax improvements in its replacement called avconv
(see Changelog for details). Please use avconv instead."

Comment: It looks like you have libav installed instead of ffmpeg (probably Debian moved to this fork). Try setting binary path to "/usr/bin/avconv".

Comment: Show us part of the code that uses fluent-ffmpeg in your project, it can provide more context.